# Maximizing trace of mixed products of two real symmetric matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, trace, symmetric-matrices, random-matrices

Let $A$, $B$ be two $N \times N$ real symmetric matrices whose entries i.i.d.r.v. from a mean 0, variance 1 distribution.

Let $I, J$ be even positive integers, and let $i_k, j_k$ for $k = 1,\ldots,n$ be arbitrary finite sequences of positive integers such that $\sum i_k = I$ and $\sum j_k = J$.

Is it true that

$\text{Tr} (A^I B^J) \geq \text{Tr}\left( A^{i_1} B^{j_1} \cdots A^{i_n} B^{j_n} \right) $?

I have run extensive numerical experiments in Mathematica on large (10K x 10K) random real symmetric matrices, and have been unable to find a counterexample; I am wondering if this might be established in a theoretical sense.

Comment: I checked many random $2\times 2$ symmetric $A,B$ and it always seems to be that $\text{tr}(AABB) \geq \text{tr}(ABAB)$.  For non-symmetric $A,B$ it is false about 71% of the time.

Comment: @JairTaylor Let $C=AB$. Then $tr(AABB)=tr(ABBA)=tr(CC^T)$ and $tr(ABAB)=tr(C^2)$. Now split $C$ into its symmetric part $H$ and skew symmetric part $K$. Since $tr(HK)=tr(KH)=0$, we have $$tr(CC^T)=tr(HH^T+KK^T)\ge tr(HH^T-KK^T)=tr(H^2+K^2)=tr(C^2).$$

Comment: @JairTaylor Or even simpler: $tr(CC^T)=\|C\|_F^2\ge\langle C,C^T\rangle=tr(C^2)$.

Comment: @user1551 Very nice!

Comment: Doing more experiments, this does seem to be true.

Comment: The initial sentence specifies that $A$ and $B$ are drawn from a certain random distribution, but then asks whether a certain inequality holds. The distribution does not seem relevant to the inequality. Are you asking (1) whether the inequality holds with high probability or (2) whether the inequality holds always, in which case the distribution doesn't matter?

Comment: My guess is that it the randomness is irrelevant and it is true in general, or for matrices satisfying an almost-surely true condition like diagonalizability. However this framing does give you something you can test empirically.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer I am asking if (2) is true, but in experiments I had to generate many $A$, $B$ to test, and so needed a systematic way to accomplish this. I decided to state the question according to how I had tested it; hence I state the distribution I used. I am sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Thanks for the response! It's an interesting, challenging question! I hope someone solves it.

Comment: Lieb and Thiering showed, for $A$ and $B$ positive semidefinite, that $\mathrm{Tr}((BAB)^r) \geq \mathrm{Tr}(B^r A^r B^r)$. Since "positive semidefinite" is equivalent to "square of a symmetric matrix", we can rewrite this as $\mathrm{Tr}((X^2 Y^2 X^2)^r) \geq \mathrm{Tr}(X^{2r} Y^{2r} X^{2r}) = \mathrm{Tr}(X^{4r} Y^{2r})$. So that is a special case of your conjecture. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_inequality#Araki%E2%80%93Lieb%E2%80%93Thirring_inequality .

Comment: Terry Tao proves $\mathrm{Tr}((AB)^{2p}) \leq \mathrm{Tr}(A^{2p} B^{2p})$ here (equation 4) https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/07/15/the-golden-thompson-inequality/ . I am trying to see if I can generalize this argument.

Comment: I had a proof strategy I was optimistic about which failed, mimicing the proof of Lemma 2 here https://arxiv.org/pdf/1408.2008.pdf . I was hoping to use the lemma $\mathrm{Tr}(A_1 A_2 \cdots A_{2n})^2 \leq \mathrm{Tr}(A_1 A_2 \cdots A_n A_n \cdots A_2 A_1) \mathrm{Tr}(A_{n+1} A_{n+2} \cdots A_{2n} A_{2n} \cdots A_{n+2} A_{n+1})$, for symmetric matrices $A_j$ and hope that the RHS were things that were inductively easier to bound. (continued)

Comment: I ran into a problem with the word $AABABBBBABAA$. The only way to cyclically shift it and break it into two subwords which each have three $A$'s and three $B$'s is $(AABABB)(BBABAA)$. However, $(AABABB)(AABABB)^T$ and $(BBABAA)(BBABAA)^T$ are both cyclic shifts of the original word, so my RHS is no simpler than my LHS. It might be worth specifically testing whether $\mathrm{Tr}(AABABBBBABAA) \leq \mathrm{Tr}(A^6 B^6)$. I believe my strategy does work for all monomials of lower degree.

Comment: With $2 \times 2$ matrices, Mathematica numeric optimization thinks this case is still true. Grrr....

Comment: One more observation and then I'll give up for now. Given any word $C_1 C_2 \cdots C_{2a+2b}$ with $2a$ copies of $A$ and $2b$ copies of $B$, we can find a cyclic shift so that $C_1 C_2 \cdots C_{a+b}$ and $C_{a+b+1} C_{a+b+2} \cdots C_{2a+2b}$ each have $a$ $A$'s and $b$ $B$'s. Then $\mathrm{Tr}(C_1 C_2 \cdots C_{2a+2b}) \leq \mathrm{Tr}(C_1 C_2 \cdots C_{a+b} C_{a+b} \cdots C_2 C_1)^{1/2} \mathrm{Tr}(C_{a+b+1} C_{a+b+2} \cdots C_{2a+2b} C_{2a+2b} \cdots C_{a+b+2} C_{a+b+1})^{1/2} = |C_1 C_2 \cdots C_{a+b}| \cdot |C_{a+b+1} C_{a+b+2} \cdots C_{2a+2b}|$ where $| \ |$ is Frobenius norm.

Comment: So it is enough to show that, of all monomials with $a$ copies of $A$ and $b$ copies of $B$, the product $A^a B^b$ has greatest Frobenius norm.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@DavidESpeyer The inequality is false for general symmetric real $A,B$. A simple example is as follows. Let $P,Q$ be two orthogonal projections in $\mathbb R^2$ so that $0<\|PQ\|_F<\frac 12$ and let $P',Q'$ be the complementary orthogonal projections. Then $U=(P-P')(Q-Q')$ is a product of two reflections, i.e., a rotation and we can easily arrange it to be a rotation by an irrational multiple of $\pi$. Then for every unit vector $x$, the orbit $U^mx:m\ge 0$ is dense on the unit circle.

In particular, if $x$ is a unit vector such that $Qx=x$ and $y$ is a unit vector such that $Py=y$, then we can find $m$ so that $U^mx\approx y$ and, thereby, $\|PU^mQ\|\approx 1$ even for the operator norm.

Now choose $a\in(0,1)$ so close to $1$ that the same holds for $U_a=(P-aP')(Q-aQ')$ instead of $U$. At last, put $A=P-aP', B=Q-aQ'$ and choose so large power $N$ that $A^n\approx P$ and $B^n\approx Q$ for all $n\ge N$. Then
$$
\|A^N(AB)^mB^N\|_F\approx \|PU_a^m Q\|_F\ge \|PU_a^mQ\|\approx 1
\\
>\frac 12>\|PQ\|_F\approx \|A^{N+m}B^{N+m}\|_F
$$
I cannot pull this trick with positive definite $A,B$ though, so that case still remains to be investigated.

**Edit** Here is a counterexample in $\mathbb R^3$ for the positive semi-definite case. Let $x,y$ be 2 orthogonal unit vectors in $\mathbb R^3$ and let $z$ be the unit vector that is linearly independent with $x,y$ and makes an angle $\pi/3$ with both of them (the exact angle value is not important as long as it is strictly smaller than $\pi/2$). For unit vectors $u,v$, let $P_u$ be the orthogonal projection to the line spanned by $u$ and let $P_{uv}$ be the orthogonal projection to the plane spanned by $u$ and $v$.

Note that $(P_{xz}P_{yz})^m\to P_z$ as $m\to\infty$. Choose a large $m$ so that $(P_{xz}P_{yz})^m\approx P_z$ with high precision. Now let $x'$ be the unit vector orthogonal to $x$ in the plane spanned by $x,z$ and let $y'$ be the unit vector orthogonal to $y$ in the plane spanned by $y,z$. We have $P_{xz}=P_x+P_{x'}$ and similarly for $P_{yz}$. Choose $a\in (0,1)$ so close to $1$ that the operators $A=P_x+aP_{x'}$ and $B=P_y+aP_{y'}$ still satisfy $(AB)^m\approx P_z$. Now choose $N$ so that for all $n\ge N$, we have $A^n\approx P_x$, $B^n\approx P_y$. Then
$$
\|A^N(AB)^mB^N\|_F\approx\|P_xP_zP_y\|_F=\frac 14
\\
>0=\|P_xP_y\|_F\approx \|A^{N+m}B^{N+m}\|_F\,.
$$
Thus there is no hope for the general version of the problem even for positive definite matrices. However, for *positive definite matrices* there are two statements that are true and not too hard to prove:

(1) The conjecture holds in $\mathbb R^2$ (so my 3-dimensional counter-example is a minimal one)

(2) If $\alpha_j\ge 0, \sum_j \alpha_j=1$, then for any positive definite $A,B$ in any dimension, we have
$$
\|C_1\dots C_m\|_F\le \|AB\|_F
$$
where each $C_j$ is either $A^{\alpha_j}B^{\alpha_j}$ or $B^{\alpha_j}A^{\alpha_j}$. This takes care of the products like $AB^2AB$, but not of $A^2BAB$, say. I wonder if this restricted type of products is actually the best we can confirm the conjecture for.

Comment: Very nice! I've been thinking about the positive definite case. Do you think it could be true that $\log | A^{\alpha_1} B^{\beta_2} \cdots A^{\alpha_r} B^{\beta_r} |_F$ is a convex function of $(\vec{\alpha}, \vec{\beta})$ in $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}^{2r}$?

Comment: @DavidESpeyer Alas, no. See the edit.

Comment: With this recipe here's an explicit counterexample to @DavidESpeyer 's conjecture: $A =\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 \\
0 & -.9 
\end{pmatrix}$, $B =\begin{pmatrix} 
-0.35 & 0.86 \\
0.86 &  0.45
\end{pmatrix}$, $|A^{10} ABABB^{10}|_F > |A^{12} B^{12}|_F$.  However, if I understand correctly the OP's question is still open.

Comment: @JairTaylor No, this is also a counterexample to the original. $|M|_F = \sqrt{\mathrm{Tr}(MM^T)}$, so $\mathrm{Tr}(A^{11}BAB^{22}ABA^{11}) > \mathrm{Tr}(A^{12}B^{24}A^{12})=\mathrm{Tr}(A^{24}B^{24})$ for those matrices.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer Ah, I see now.  I'll award the bounty then.

Comment: Still, I wonder if the probability of the OP's inequality tends to 1 as the dimension increases.  The OP was originally interested in very large matrices and these counterexamples are rather special.